# MassTransit:get error inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange, received 'fanout' but current is 'topic''

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have exchange(topic)->(with routing key)exchange(direct)->queue
And my exchange topic have name for example **"command-exchange"**
So I want to send request to my exchange(topic) specified name "command-exchange"
But I get error **"for exchange "command-exchange" fanout but current is topic"**

*producer code:*

```
var endPoint =  _mobileServiceBus.Bus.CreateRequestClient<IRequestCommandSocket,IResponseCommandSocket>
                (new Uri($"exchange:command-exchange"),TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var response = await endPoint.Request(new
{
   Type = "A",
   TopicKey = "A.B.C.D"
});
```

configuration code:

```
sbc.Message<IRequestCommandSocket>(e => e.SetEntityName(WebSocketMQConst.ExchangeName.SocketCommandExchange));

                    sbc.Publish<IRequestCommandSocket>(e =>
                    {
                        e.ExchangeType = ExchangeType.Topic;
                    });

                    sbc.Send<IRequestCommandSocket>(e =>
                    {
                        e.UseRoutingKeyFormatter(context => context.Message.TopicKey.ToString());
                    });

                    sbc.ReceiveEndpoint("command-queue", e =>
                    {
                        e.BindMessageExchanges = false;
                        e.Bind<IRequestCommandSocket>(a =>
                       {
                           a.RoutingKey = "A.B.C.#";
                       });
                        e.Consumer<CommandConsumer>(provider);
                    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to add `?type=topic` to the end of the Uri.